# Publish to random host port while using --network=host

Tags: docker

I am trying to access a host URL from within a docker container. I would also like to publish container ports to random ports on the host.

```
docker run --network=host -P -d somerepo/someimage
```

However, it looks like the `-P` and the `--net=host` options don't want to co-exist as I don't see any port mappings created when I run a `docker ports <container_id>`

Am I missing something obvious here?

PS: There is no docker-machine involved. Docker engine is running directly on the host machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `-P` or `-p` with `--net=host` because that doesn't make any sense.  When you're using `--net=host`, IF a process in a container opens a port THEN that port is open on your host. No mapping is required, because your container process are running in the host's network environment.

Comment: Agree. What I am really trying to achieve is a random host port binding without having to change the Dockerfile.

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you're trying to do?  You could obviously just stop using `--net=host`, and then use `-p`/`-P` normally.

Comment: I have a service running on the host, whose URL is http://localhost:8080. I need to be able to access this URL from within my container (https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome/ specifically). So, I would like "localhost" from inside the container to resolve to the host's address.

Comment: Why not just bind the host service to the docker bridge, so that from inside the container you can access it at the default gateway address?

Comment: That's a good suggestion - in theory I could do that. Only constraint for me is that I want to be able to do this without changing the code used for running the service. I will try that and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't get my service to bind to a different network interface due to some issues with the framework I am using. So, I had to use the `--net=host` option. I have now come up with a workaround to find a random unused port on the host machine using `netstat -lat | grep $(shuf -i 2000-65000 -n 1)` which would return `1` if the port is available and `0` otherwise. I then use this to override the WebDriver grid port.